# How to resolve unresolved identifier error in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have edited these lines in `podfile` also:-

```
  pod ‘Firebase’
  pod ‘Firebase/Auth’
  pod ‘Firebase/Database’
```

In ViewController.swift file:-
firebase url is not working

`let firebase_ref = firebase(url: "https://project-214666856365171358.firebaseio.com/")`

> error:- use of unresolved identifier 'firebase'

Comment: Do you have 'import Firebase' in your ViewController?

Comment: Yes import firebase is working,error is in the url line

Comment: How do you know the import worked? Are any other firebase methods defined?

Comment: Yes,I think firebase updated their method

Comment: You should replace the smart quotes with '